Connecting Toradex Verdin iMX8M Mini to LCD Display with RGB 24bit interface with I2C Touch
I´m building my base board that uses the Toradex Verdin iMX8M Mini SOM module.
My base board uses the same electronics from Toradex Verdin Development Board and exports the SOM MIPI DSI interface for LCD connection (named Display Serial Interface 1x Quad Lane MIPI DSI - up to 1920x1080 at the SOM DataSheet).
We need to use a 10.1 LCD Panel with touch screen, and 90% of the market available displays use the RGB 24bit interface, like the this DWIN unit as an example
What do I need to do to convert my iMX8M Mini output to DWIN´s RGB_24bit 50PIN_0.5mm for output? And the I2C touch input?
What type of circuitry and architecture do I need to use? Toradex has this so called DSI to LVDS adapter, but I can´t see how to connect it to RGB_24bit that comes from the LCD panel.

You need a chip which converts i.MX DSI to 24-bit parallel for your display.
If such chips do not exist you need to go via some other interface with two adapting chips, such as DSI to LVDS and LVDS to 24-bit parallel bus.
For touch input the i.MX is likely to have I2C already.
